# RESTful Web Service is auto flushing static Hashtable var and Httpruntime.cache object automatically after 20 mins

Tags: c#, wcf, caching, rest

I have a **WCF RESTful web service**, I have implemented cache mechanism using HashTable. but the problem is **it is getting flushes/count=0 automatically after 20 mins** if its kept in idle state or no connection is made to it.
Can u please suggest what could be the possible solution to it

I even tried using **httpruntime.cache** to achieve the same and removed hashtable but the outcome was same

by some R&D i found this thing could solve the issue but it didnt

```
[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.Single, ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Multiple)]
```

Comment: Are you hosting your service in IIS?

Comment: @BrianDriscoll Yes I have hosted it on IIS

Comment: @BrianDriscoll apart from Joachim's answer, any other thing i need to configure??

Comment: I can't think of anything off the top of my head.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds very much like you're hosting in IIS and did not configure [Idle Timeout settings](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771956(v=ws.10).aspx), which means your application pool will be automatically shut down after (default) 20 minutes of idle time.

Comment: sounds interesting... let me try it :)

Comment: any other thing i need to configure or that will do?